# Refresh Materialized View over DB Link

Tags: oracle, view, refresh, dblink, materialized

DB **B** is connected over DB-Link with DB **A**. On **B** I created materialized view **mav_test**, that took about 40 seconds and works fine. If I try to refresh **mav_test** now e.g. with 'execute dbms_mview.refresh('mav_test','c');' and other commands, System **B** is turing in empty. It's the same query, so what's going wrong? I realy need help.

Comment: by the way, I'm working with Oracle SQL Developer. Oracle Version is 11. The idea is, to refresh view whenever a stored procedure is called (once a month).

Comment: Get the query for the MV and run it when you are logged in as the same user that owns the MV. Does it return results?

Comment: that works perfect. i also can delete and create it again inside a stroed precedure (both with execute immidiate), but that's not the solution i want.

Comment: Not sure. Is the MV currently still empty? If so, I'd check if it's marked as valid, and try recompiling it before doing another Complete refresh. (p.s. might be able to get more advice from the dba stackexchange.)